# Track daily, weekly, monthly computer usage?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, fedora, daemon

I am looking for a simple program to run in the background and track my computer usage (number of hours) with simple reporting for daily, weekly and monthly time frames. My environment:

- Fedora Desktop
- Xfce environment

I don't need it to track what I was doing specifically. Tracking the general uptime is enough for me.

It should, however, be very easy to extract the reporting with no coding, scripting or complex commands involved.

Comment: The usage of what?

Comment: The usage of my computer.

Comment: Perhaps uptime (the time the computer has power)? Then `last` will tell you as it is recorded (utmp/wtmp).

Comment: Exact environment (operating system, version) and usage (desktopm web server, ...) are important details. All Unixy systems do record activity, check log files, and so on. A comprehensive overview is the one by [Brendan Gregg](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html), he has a whole book on the matter.

Comment: Do you want to have the time the computer is on, or do you wish to track which programs operate, or only for specific programs (e.g. how long a web browser is open)? The more detailed, the more difficult it will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Linux computer will by default already record events like boot and shutdown times.

If you wish to see the durations from Linux booting until shutdown (roughly the times the computer had power), you can use the system's default accounting (utmp/wtmp) for that.

Use these shell commands (as a normal user, no root rights necessary):

```
# last reboot
reboot   system boot  5.5.4-1-default  Fri Feb 21 14:07   still running
reboot   system boot  5.5.2-1-default  Thu Feb 20 12:53 - 14:02  (01:08)
(...)
```

This shows you boot times and the duration (in brackets at the end) that the computer was booted.

NB This does not show times when the computer was asleep (suspend to disk or RAM), that would require more complicated work.

If you wish to see the time for last week etc. you can do that with newer versions of the `last` commands using the new `--since` and `--until` options:

```
last --since "`date --date='monday 3 weeks ago' +%Y-%m-%d`" \
     --until "`date --date='monday 2 weeks ago' +%Y-%m-%d`" \
     reboot
```

which gives you the times (last reboot) for the specified week(s).  The same works for months, here given in one command line:

```
last --since "`date --date='2 months ago' +%Y-%m-%d`" --until "`date --date='1 month ago' +%Y-%m-%d`" reboot
```

which will use the 1st day of the month by default -- which seems to be what you want.

The command lines above call the `last` command (from util-linux) with dates that look like `2019-12-27` which is one of few formats accepted by the command.  We use the `date` command (from GNU coreutils) to generate that format with the `%Y-%m-%d` format string, telling `date` which date to show in a more human readable format accepted by it.