# Get total time system has been used today - in minutes

Tags: shell-script, last, uptime

I want to set a daily limit as to how long my computer can be on in a single day. In order to do so, I'm writing a cron script that will take appropriate action when certain milestones are reached (showing an alert when time is running out; shutting down the computer when time is up).

The part I'm struggling with is getting the total uptime in minutes for the day. I have looked at [this uptime script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321855/how-to-get-real-uptime), but I feel that using [last](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569228/track-daily-weekly-monthly-computer-usage) is simplest.

`$ last -s today`

Gives me something like:

```
user     tty1                          Sat Jul 22 14:09   still logged in
user     tty1                          Sat Jul 22 11:50 - down   (01:56)
```

I am currently trying to convert the hours in parentheses to minutes, and also converting the 'still logged in' session to minutes. It can work, but I feel like all these options are a bit convoluted.

Is there a simpler way to get the total uptime (excluding suspend/sleep) in minutes, or should I find a workaround for these types of outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Execute this on the shell, to get the total `uptime` in minutes for the current session:

`echo "Total uptime today (minutes): $(( ($(date +%s) - $(date -d "$(uptime -s)" +%s)) / 60 ))"`

Execute this with `awk` and `/proc/uptime`:

`awk '{print "Total uptime for the machine (minutes):", int($1 / 60)}' /proc/uptime`

**Update:**

The first two commands only display the runtime of the current session.

I have now implemented it in a small bash script, combining `last` and `/proc/uptime.` Maybe you can achieve it with a one-liner for the shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

sessions_uptime=$(last | grep "$(date '+%b %d')" | grep 'reboot' | grep -v 'still running' | awk '{print $NF}' | tr -d '()' | awk -F: '{sum_minutes+=$1*60+$2} END {print sum_minutes}')
current_time=$(awk '{print int($1 / 60)}' /proc/uptime)

total_uptime=$((sessions_uptime + current_time))
echo "TOTAL CURRENT RUNTIME OF THE DAY: ${total_uptime}"
```

`sessions_uptime`

- Filters out all `reboots` from `last` except for `still running` and calculates the time in minutes from all sessions of the day.

`current_time`

- Calculates the current runtime of the session.

`total_uptime`

- Outputs the sum of both values, i.e., the total uptime of the day, including the current session. I have executed this on Debian 11.7; I cannot say if it works on all systems.

**Update2:**

```
#!/bin/bash

get_minutes() {
  local h=${1%%:*}
  local m=${1#*:}
  echo $((10#$h * 60 + 10#$m))
}

sessions_uptime=$(last | grep "$(date '+%b %d')" | grep -E 'reboot|suspended' | grep -v 'still running' | awk '{print $NF}' | tr -d '()' | awk -F: '{sum_minutes+=$1*60+$2} END {print sum_minutes}')

current_uptime_seconds=$(awk '{print int($1)}' /proc/uptime)

total_uptime=$((sessions_uptime + current_uptime_seconds / 60))
echo "TOTAL CURRENT RUNTIME OF THE DAY: ${total_uptime} minutes"
```

Identify which eventualities need to be considered and adjust the scripts if the approach is suitable.

I found these status messages for `last` on the internet, but I cannot confirm if all of them are accurate.

"**reboot**"

> The system has been rebooted properly

**"shutdown"**

> The system has been shut down properly

**"suspended"**

> The system has been put into suspend or hibernation mode

**"resumed"**

> The system has been restored from suspend or hibernation mode

**"crash"**

> The system has been rebooted due to an error or crash

**"down"**

> The system has been shut down, which can also occur due to power failures or hardware issues

**"gone - no logout"**

> Can be displayed when a user abruptly ends the connection without logging out properly

Comment: Fantastic, that is SO much simpler than the scripts I found!

Comment: Wait... this only shows the uptime of the current session. It does NOT calculate the total uptime of today. Any way to get today's total uptime?

Comment: Somehow it doesn't seem to be the case. If you look at my output from `last` in the original question, you will see I have two sessions (one currently active, and one where I started and turned off the computer in the morning... a session lasting 1h56). This first session of the day is not included in neither the first or second script. Both return the same value for me.

Comment: This will break spectacularly if the system is suspended and resumed daily. This will break spectacularly if the system is never power cycled. In short it will break more often than not.

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov | Are you referring to the first two commands or the bash script in the update?

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov | Do you have a different approach on how to solve this, considering all eventualities? To tackle this, what factors should one consider? I attempted to achieve it in a one-liner, but perhaps my approach was flawed. Can you utilize `loginctl` to apply better filtering for this purpose?

Comment: Oh, wait, what about turning your system on and not using it at all?

Comment: @BlockchainOffice thanks for this updated script. However, it does not seem to take into account when the system is suspended. Today I had the computer on for an hour in the morning and an hour in the evening, and it reported 10+ hours using this script. The `last` output doesn't include suspend on my machine, it seems. When I use journalctl it does report time the machine was suspended, but I'm not sure how to combine that output with this (also, that would require sudo access it seems). Any ideas?